# SQL Server Express with Mangement Studio does not install management studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I downloaded the installation for SQL Server Express 2008 with Management Studio from here:

[Download SQL Express 2008 with Management Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22985)

I ran the install and installed the SQL Server Services w/o issue, except there are no client-side tools.  Management Studio Express did not install and I can find no way to install it. I have followed numerous posts on Microsoft's social sites, but no success.  The posts that seem to make the most sense to me suggest running install and add features.  When I do this, Management Studio is NOT listed as a feature to add:

[image]

As you can see by the image `SQL Client Connectivity SDK` is the ONLY option for added features.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.  During the initial installation step where it checks pre-requisites, it found I did not have the PowerTools installed.  I then installed the PowerTools and re-ran the checks and saw the screen above.  But after rebooting, I then saw the 'Management Tools - Basic' option visible and checked.